# Transform ResponseEntity<?> to stream

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am making a call to external service and the response is

```
ResponseEntity<?>
```

The goal is to set this response to a String that is Base64. After some research I found out that I can do this with a byte array like this

```
byte[] rawBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray('put stream here');
String data = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(rawBytes);
```

What is the way to transform this ResponseEntity to an  input stream so I can use further in my implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can directly fetch what you are getting in ResponseEntity i.e. if you know what is ? (for example ResponseEntity of type String/Integer/Object)

Try below code,

```
ResponseEntity<?> response;
response.getBody().toString().getBytes(); or String.valueOf(response.getBody).getBytes();
```